# What does "outstubborn" mean?

Tags: meaning, quotes

Came across the following quote:

> Never try to **outstubborn** a cat.

Googling did not help. What does Outstubborn mean?

Comment: *Stubborn* is an adjective. The prefix *out-* takes a verb instead, in the sense used in the context. *Outstubborn* is not a word, but used for literary effect (― Robert A. Heinlein, *Time Enough for Love* http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/353.Time_Enough_for_Love ).

Comment: @Kris And especially *outsmart* uses *smart* as a verb. To beat opponent by feeling more pain, right?

Comment: @Kris: The question is not whether "outstubborn" is a word (but see my other comment). The question is what it means. Bad form on the -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Be more stubborn than" or "surpass or outdo in terms of stubbornness".

It's modeled on words like "outdo" or "outsmart".

It's not a standard word, *per se*, but it's a common construction. See [the prefix "out-" in the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/out-?s=t).

Less common overall is the attaching of the prefix "out-" to an adjective ("stubborn"), or really anything [other than a verb](http://www.wordfind.com/starts-with/out/), which gives the construction a jocular or lowbrow quality (at least in a neologism), but the construction is understandable, and cf. "outsmart" and "outclass".

As for other adjectives used in this way, a Google search returns evidence for "outstupid", and other examples are undoubtedly available.

Your example sentence appears to have originated in Robert A. Heinlein's [*Time Enough for Love*](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/66041-never-try-to-outstubborn-a-cat) (1973), and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) gives another instance of "outstubborn" in Linda Lael Miller's *The Women of Primrose Creek* (2002).

Comment: -1 Please see my comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris: See edited version. Also, see the definition of a word [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/word?s=t) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word).

Answer (score 0):

Just like *outwit* or *outsmart* <sup>[M-W](http://i.word.com/idictionary/outsmart)</sup> mean to *to gain advantage over someone by being more smart*, "outstubborn" would mean *to be more stubborn than someone*, *to gain advantage by being more stubborn*.